# Как отпарсить данные SQL через Python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, парсер, pymysql

Мало знаком с SQL, была поставлена задача извлечь данные столбца таблицы.

Есть такая таблица:

```
CREATE TABLE `homeworks`(
Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
Geography TEXT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Id)
);

INSERT INTO `homeworks`(Geography) ADD ('Ничего не задали');
INSERT INTO `homeworks`(Geography) ADD ('Параграф 20');
INSERT INTO `homeworks`(Geography) ADD ('Подготовиться к контрольной');
```

Как мне отпарсить данные столбца «Geography» так, чтобы я мог работать с ними как со строкой?

Comment: в чем проблема выполнить select и работать уже в python, используя драйвер для работы с субд

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужен инструмент для подключения к базе данных и взаимодействия, например, [SQL Alchemy](https://www.sqlalchemy.org/). Затем уже используя его, можно выполнить `SELECT * FROM homeworks`, где вы получите все нужные вам строчки.